# Email not sending correctly

Tags: php, html, email

I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird with xampp - mercury, apache, mysql

The problem is when I order one product, it sends the order email with everything in place. It looks like this for one product:

```
Order date and time: July 1, 2012, 11:04 am
Thank you for your order at our online shop!
Your order information:


    Product ID: 1991001
    Brand: Razer
    Model: Mamba Elite Wireless Gaming Mouse
    Price per item: 129.99
    Amount of item: 1
    Total cost: 129.99
    _________________________________________________|
    1To follow your odertracking please remember your order ID and customer ID
    Order ID: 116
    Customer ID: 6
    Link to track your order: Ordertracking system
```

When I order 5 products, it will only show 4 products in the email and will look like this:

```
Order date and time: July 1, 2012, 11:08 am
Thank you for your order at our online shop!
Your order information:


Product ID: 1991001
Brand: Razer
Model: Mamba Elite Wireless Gaming Mouse
Price per item: 129.99
Amount of item: 1
Total cost: 129.99
_________________________________________________|
1 Product ID: 1991002
Brand: Razer
Model: Imperator Expert Ergonomic Gaming Mouse
Price per item: 79.99
Amount of item: 1
Total cost: 79.99
_________________________________________________|
2 Product ID: 1991003
Brand: Razer
Model: Orochi Elite Mobile Gaming Mouse
Price per item: 79.99
Amount of item: 3
Total cost: 239.96999999999997
_________________________________________________|
3 Product ID: 1991004
Brand: Razer
Model: Expert Ambidextrous Gaming Mouse
Price per item: 79.99
Amount of item: 1
T
```

I don't see the 5th product and also don't see:
`To follow your odertracking please remember your order ID and customer ID
    Order ID: 116
    Customer ID: 6
    Link to track your order: Ordertracking system`

Why and how can I fix this problem?

Here is the code for the email. email.php, at the end you see `$to = $email;`

```
<?php
//var_dump($_GET);

//collect all information
$name = $_GET["name"];
$surname = $_GET["surname"];
$city = $_GET["city"];
$postalcode = $_GET["postalcode"];
$phonenumber = $_GET["phonenumber"];
$email = $_GET["email"];

$i = 1;
while (isset($_GET["Product_ID_".$i])) {
    $productid = $_GET["Product_ID_".$i];
    $brand = $_GET["Brand_".$i];
    $model = $_GET["Model_".$i];
    $price = $_GET["Price_".$i];
    $amount = $_GET["Amount_products_".$i];
    $totalcost = $_GET["Total_cost_".$i];
    $i++;
}

$image = "includes/images/mouse_4.jpg";


$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a");



//connect to database
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Can't connect");
mysql_select_db("shoppingcart", $connection) or die ("Can't connect");  

//check if already customer
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email='$email'");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);


    if ($rows) 
    {
      echo '<br>Welcome back ' . $name .' '. $surname. '<br>';
    }
    else
    {
        //if new customer, add to database
        $customer = "INSERT INTO customer (customerid, name, surname, email, city, postalcode, phonenumber) VALUES ('', '$name', '$surname', '$email', '$city', '$postalcode', '$phonenumber')";
        if (!mysql_query($customer,$connection))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            echo "Sorry, there was an error";
        }
        echo "New customer added" . "<br />";
        echo '<br>Welcome as our new customer ' . $name . ' '. $surname;

        mysql_close($connection);   
    }

//connect to database
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Can't connect");
mysql_select_db("shoppingcart", $connection) or die ("Can't connect");


//get customer id
$res = mysql_query("SELECT customerid FROM customer WHERE email='$email'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
 $customerid=$row['customerid'];
}
    //add new ordertracking
    $ordertracking = "INSERT INTO `ordertracking` (orderid, customerid, email, progress, date) VALUES ('', '$customerid', '$email', 'Pending', '$date')";
    if (!mysql_query($ordertracking,$connection))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            echo "Sorry, there was an error";
        }
        echo "New order added" . "<br />";

        mysql_close($connection);

//connect to database
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Can't connect");
mysql_select_db("shoppingcart", $connection) or die ("Can't connect");

//get order id
$vol = mysql_query("SELECT orderid FROM ordertracking WHERE email='$email'");
while($volume=mysql_fetch_array($vol))
{
 $orderid = $volume['orderid'];
}
    // add new order
    $order = "INSERT INTO `order` (orderid, customerid, productid, brand, model, price, amount, totalcost, image) VALUES ('$orderid', '$customerid', '$productid', '$brand' , '$model', '$price', '$amount', '$totalcost', '$image')";
    if (!mysql_query($order,$connection))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            echo "Sorry, there was an error";
        }
        echo "New order added" . "<br />";

        mysql_close($connection);


$to = $email;
$subject = "Order information of: ";

$headers = "From: " . "postmaster@localhost" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". "postmaster@localhost" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Dear ' . $name . ' ' . $surname .  ',</h1>' . '<br />';
$message .= 'Order date and time: ' . $date . '<br />';
$message .= 'Thank you for your order at our online shop!' . '<br />';
$message .= 'Your order information: ' . '<br /><br /><br />';
$i = 1;
while (isset($_GET["Product_ID_".$i])) {
    $productid = $_GET["Product_ID_".$i];
    $brand = $_GET["Brand_".$i];
    $model = $_GET["Model_".$i];
    $price = $_GET["Price_".$i];
    $amount = $_GET["Amount_products_".$i];
    $totalcost = $_GET["Total_cost_".$i];

    $message .= ' Product ID: ' . $productid . "<br />" .
                'Brand: '. $brand . "<br />" .
                'Model: ' . $model . "<br />" .
                'Price per item: ' . $price . "<br />" .
                'Amount of item: ' . $amount . "<br />" .
                'Total cost: ' . $totalcost . "<br />" .
                '_________________________________________________| ' . "<br />" .
    $i++;
}
$message .= 'To follow your odertracking please remember your order ID and customer ID' . '<br />';
$message .= 'Order ID: ' . $orderid . '<br />';
$message .= 'Customer ID: ' . $customerid . '<br />';
$message .= 'Link to track your order: ' . '<a href="http://localhost/school/shoppingcart/ordertracking.php">Ordertracking system</a>' . '<br />';

$message .= '</body></html>';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="3;ordertracking.php">
```

EDIT for var dump outpu:

```
array(38) { ["Product_ID_1"]=> string(7) "1991001" ["Brand_1"]=> string(5) "Razer" ["Model_1"]=> string(33) "Mamba Elite Wireless Gaming Mouse" ["Price_1"]=> string(6) "129.99" ["Amount_products_1"]=> string(1) "1" ["Total_cost_1"]=> string(6) "129.99" ["Product_ID_2"]=> string(7) "1991002" ["Brand_2"]=> string(5) "Razer" ["Model_2"]=> string(39) "Imperator Expert Ergonomic Gaming Mouse" ["Price_2"]=> string(5) "79.99" ["Amount_products_2"]=> string(1) "1" ["Total_cost_2"]=> string(5) "79.99" ["Product_ID_3"]=> string(7) "1991003" ["Brand_3"]=> string(5) "Razer" ["Model_3"]=> string(32) "Orochi Elite Mobile Gaming Mouse" ["Price_3"]=> string(5) "79.99" ["Amount_products_3"]=> string(1) "1" ["Total_cost_3"]=> string(5) "79.99" ["Product_ID_4"]=> string(7) "1991004" ["Brand_4"]=> string(5) "Razer" ["Model_4"]=> string(32) "Expert Ambidextrous Gaming Mouse" ["Price_4"]=> string(5) "79.99" ["Amount_products_4"]=> string(1) "1" ["Total_cost_4"]=> string(5) "79.99" ["Product_ID_5"]=> string(7) "1991005" ["Brand_5"]=> string(5) "Razer" ["Model_5"]=> string(62) "Battlefield 3â„¢ Razer Imperator Expert Ergonomic Gaming mouse" ["Price_5"]=> string(5) "79.99" ["Amount_products_5"]=> string(1) "1" ["Total_cost_5"]=> string(5) "79.99" ["name"]=> string(1) "s" ["surname"]=> string(1) "s" ["city"]=> string(1) "s" ["postalcode"]=> string(1) "s" ["phonenumber"]=> string(1) "s" ["email"]=> string(17) "klant-x@localhost" ["x"]=> string(2) "85" ["y"]=> string(2) "12" }
```

Comment: It seems your encountering some error that terminates the script. I can only suggest to iclude error_reporting(-1);ini_set('display_errors', 'stdout'); at the top of the script and check what it complains about

Comment: Are you passing all that product information via the GET query string? The query string has a maximum length, being browser specific. Also it will fail if you don't uriencode the values, especially the strings, like model and brand

Comment: just under <?php... ? Nothing happened. I don't see any errors. Where do I have to see the errors?

Comment: @freefaller whenever I use `var_dump($_GET);` I see all the products. It also shows all the products in the shoppincart, but when I hit checkout it only shows 4 products in the email, but the problem here is it does not show everything. I don't think it is related to GET. Because the ending message has nothing to do with GET. It just not showing everything in the email. I am pretty sure it is sending everything to the email.

Comment: is the data passed via $_GET html free? Maybe there is a tag like </html>
Could you edit your post to include what is outputted with var_export($_GET)?

Comment: Fair enough, but it's still not going to help in the long run, especially once you code is being used in the wild.

Comment: @karka91 I've edited my question with the var dump output

Comment: the only funny thing I can find is the utf problem in "Battlefield 3â„¢ Razer Imperator Expert Ergonomic Gaming mouse" but this should not have any effect in simple output. On a side note - your script is very insecure and very vulnerable to SQL injection. Consider sanitizing you inputs and using PDO instead of the outdated mysql extension

Comment: @karka91 I know it's not secure, it's for an simple project for school, not for actual use.

Comment: Please try to change the model of the product I mentioned before. It seems the script actually gets stuck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the passing of all that information via the query string.

Instead, you should sent it via `POST` based form, and then use `$_POST`.

If you're already using a form, then just change the `method` attribute to `POST`

Comment: using post instead of get will only give errors and the entire script will not work at all

Comment: Can you explain how it will cause errors when I say to use `$_POST`?

Comment: he probably did not change $_GET to $_POST inside the script

Comment: I will get Undefined variable: after hitting on checkout for everything and var dump shows array(0) { }

Comment: @F4LLCON, as karka91 says, you need to change all instances of `$_GET` to `$_POST` in your code. Although as you say the var_dump on the GET returns everything you expect, then I'm not convinced it will work, but I still think passing everything via query string is the wrong approach

Comment: I'm giving up, this script has two problems, one not sending all the products to my database, only the last product and one is that the email is not showing all the data. only the first 4 products. It's like the email has line limit or something. Well have to show this tomorrow at school and I am just giving up on the two problems. The teacher has to deal with it. Thank you I will upvote your posts but can't flag it as finished

Comment: @F4LLCON the reason for the insert is you're overwriting each variable in the while loop, meaning it will end up with the last one, and you need an insert statement for each product. Good luck, thanks for the upvote